# Could other developers' IAP test user accounts buy in my apps?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In the server side, I'm doing something like:

```
if(tryIsRealAccount or tryIsSandBoxAccount)
    {buy...}
```

It's a MUST when my app is reviewing by Apple. But should I close sandBox-trying after review?

It may be a silly question, but I really wanna make sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any reason to close testing the sandbox - you'll only need to turn it on again next time you submit an app for review (because [Apple's reviewers use the sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891555/push-notifications-app-submitting-to-review/27891561#27891561)).

Other developers won't be able to use sandbox users to purchase items in your production apps. I just tested it in a production app with my test user credentials, and it doesn't work without payment information:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It'll be easy and safe then:)